# Service side PDFMake basic script returns error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, pdf-generation, pdfmake

I'm working on a Web-Application on which i need to generate PDFs using `pdfmake`library. 
I have no problems when running it on client side (For printing) but I can't manage to get it to work on server side using `node.js` (to save my pdfs on the server).

My server is running on `linux` and `node.js` and `npm` are correctly installed. 
I also installed the `pdfmake` package using `sudo npm i pdfmake`. The module seems to be correctly installed as it is listed when using `npm ls`.

I then tried to run a simple script to generate a basic pdf :

```
var pdfmake = require('pdfmake');


var fonts = {
        Roboto: {
                normal: 'fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
                bold: 'fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
                italics: 'fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
                bolditalics: 'fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
        }
};

var PdfPrinter = require('../src/printer');
var printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);
var fs = require('fs');

var docDefinition = {
        content: [
                'First paragraph',
                'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, this line will be divided into at least two lines'
        ]
};

var pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('pdfs/basics.pdf'));
pdfDoc.end();
```

When executing (`sudo node pdftest.js`) this script return the following error  : `Error: Cannot find module '../src/printer'`

For me, this `/printer` folder should be located within the `pdfmake` folder, so I shouldn't have this error.

I tried to reinstall the package by running again `sudo npm i pdfmake` but it didn't change anything.

Also, this is what I get when I install it :

```
/home/odroid
`-- pdfmake@0.1.36
  `-- linebreak@0.3.0
    `-- brfs@1.6.1
      `-- static-module@2.2.5
        `-- falafel@2.1.0
          `-- acorn@5.6.1

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/odroid/package.json'
npm WARN odroid No description
npm WARN odroid No repository field.
npm WARN odroid No README data
npm WARN odroid No license field.
```

Does anyone already got this problem ? Can you help me out ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to `printer` is specified incorrectly.
If you install the package with `npm install` it's gonna be placed in `node_modules` folder. You can read more about package installation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally).

So in order to run your code, I have changed the path to:

```
var PdfPrinter = require('./node_modules/pdfmake/src/printer');
```

Also please make sure:

- you have `fonts` folder and Roboto exists inside
- you have created the pdfs folder (`mkdir pdfs`)

I didn't touch the rest and was able to generate this document:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Antonio ! I noticed that also. I was thinking that the node-modules where installed in one and only folder but I did understand that they are actually creating folder where you are. So if I make an npm install in /home/ it will create /home/node_module and will do the same in another folder. It is more clear now ;)